# Trouble configuring Velocity with Spring for a JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, velocity

I'm using Spring 3.0.5, Maven 3.0.3, JUnit 4 and Velocity 1.6.2.  When I run my JUnit test, it is not able to locate a velocity template I created.  The error I get is:

```
2011-07-08 16:16:19,575 [main] ERROR test.com.myco.systems.leadsmonitor.quartz.TestReportQuartzJob  - JobExecutionException
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: Exception in execute [See nested exception: org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'email_template.vm']
at com.myco.systems.leadsmonitor.quartz.ReportQuartzJob.executeInternal(ReportQuartzJob.java:55)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)
at test.com.myco.systems.leadsmonitor.quartz.TestReportQuartzJob.testJob(TestReportQuartzJob.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
```

I copied the template in question to both src/main/resources and src/test/resources .  I have my velocity.properties file in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/velocity.properties.  Its contents are:

```
# uncomment the next two lines to load templates from the
# classpath (WEB-INF/classes)
resource.loader=class
class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader

# comment the next two lines to stop loading templates from the
# file system
#resource.loader=file
#file.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader


# additional config for file system loader only.. tell Velocity where the root
# directory is for template loading.  You can define multiple root directories
# if you wish, I just use the one here.  See the text below for a note about
# the ${webapp.root}
#file.resource.loader.path=${webapp.root}/WEB-INF/velocity


# caching should be 'true' in production systems, 'false' is a development
# setting only.  Change to 'class.resource.loader.cache=false' for classpath
# loading
file.resource.loader.cache=false
```

Here is how I'm trying to populate my template.  The JUnit test invokes this code:

```
    /*
     * first, get and initialize an engine
     */
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.init();

    /*
     * Build the template
     */
    final String emailBody = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(ve, "email_template.vm", map);

    sendMessage(subject, emailBody);
```

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
ve.setProperty(VelocityEngine.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_PATH, "./src/test/resources/");
ve.setProperty(VelocityEngine.FILE_RESOURCE_LOADER_CACHE, false);
ve.init();
```

Comment: I assume you meant for this code to go in the JUnit test?  If so, I followed your suggestion (putting this at the very beginning of the test), but no dice.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a VelocityEngine using the VelocityEngineFactoryBean as follows:

```
VelocityEngineFactoryBean vefb = new VelocityEngineFactoryBean();
    Map<String, Object> velocityPropertiesMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    velocityPropertiesMap.put("resource.loader", "class");
    velocityPropertiesMap.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
    vefb.setVelocityPropertiesMap(velocityPropertiesMap);
    velocityEngine = vefb.createVelocityEngine();
```

Then the following statement should work

```
VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, template, model);
```